# Error declaring multiple table variables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem declaring multible table variables in Microsoft SQL Server. Trying to separate the tables with comma but seems to give me some syntax errors.

Code looks like this. Show both code as sample and as a picture in order for you to see the error marks:

```
DECLARE
@StructuredProducts TABLE(
    StructuredProductId INT
    ,ArrangerIdv2 INT
    ,ISIN VARCHAR(50)
    ,InstrumentId INT
    ,Caption VARCHAR(100)
    ,DbRegDate DATE
    ,EndDate DATE
),
@PriceDataOld TABLE(
    StructuredProductId INT
    ,FinalDate DATE
    ,FinalPriceDate DATE
    ,FinalPrice DECIMAL(9,3)
    ,FinalPriceSek DECIMAL(9,3)
),
@PriceDataEarlyExercise TABLE(
    StructuredProductId INT
    ,EEDate DATE
    ,EEPriceDate DATE
    ,EEPrice DECIMAL(9,3)
    ,EEPriceSek DECIMAL(9,3)
),
@PriceDataActive TABLE(
    StructuredProductId INT
    ,ActiveDate DATE
    ,ActivePriceDate DATE
    ,ActivePrice DECIMAL(9,3)
    ,ActivePriceSek DECIMAL(9,3)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Use a `DECLARE` for each table, instead of a `,`

Comment: Want the code to be as neat as possible. Isn't comma the way to declare multiple variables?

Comment: @David tables and variables are completely different  please check the syntax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To address your comment

> Isn't comma the way to declare multiple variables?

well, yes a comma can be used to declare multiple *local* variables and *cursors*, but **not** *table* variables - the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) explicitly say this:

> `n`
>
> Is a placeholder indicating that multiple variables can be specified
>   and assigned values. When declaring **table** variables, the **table**
>   variable must be the only variable being declared in the `DECLARE`
>   statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL server we have to create table like this format only there is no other styles 

 DECLARE @StructuredProducts TABLE(
StructuredProductId INT
,ArrangerIdv2 INT
,ISIN VARCHAR(50)
,InstrumentId INT
,Caption VARCHAR(100)
,DbRegDate DATE
,EndDate DATE
) ;
DECLARE @PriceDataOld TABLE(
StructuredProductId INT
,FinalDate DATE
,FinalPriceDate DATE
,FinalPrice DECIMAL(9,3)
,FinalPriceSek DECIMAL(9,3)
);
DECLARE @PriceDataEarlyExercise TABLE(
StructuredProductId INT
,EEDate DATE
,EEPriceDate DATE
,EEPrice DECIMAL(9,3)
,EEPriceSek DECIMAL(9,3)
);
DECLARE @PriceDataActive TABLE(
StructuredProductId INT
,ActiveDate DATE
,ActivePriceDate DATE
,ActivePrice DECIMAL(9,3)
,ActivePriceSek DECIMAL(9,3)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

change it like below

```
DECLARE
@StructuredProducts TABLE(
    StructuredProductId INT
    ,ArrangerIdv2 INT
    ,ISIN VARCHAR(50)
    ,InstrumentId INT
    ,Caption VARCHAR(100)
    ,DbRegDate DATE
    ,EndDate DATE
);DECLARE
@PriceDataOld TABLE(
    StructuredProductId INT
    ,FinalDate DATE
    ,FinalPriceDate DATE
    ,FinalPrice DECIMAL(9,3)
    ,FinalPriceSek DECIMAL(9,3)
);DECLARE
@PriceDataEarlyExercise TABLE(
    StructuredProductId INT
    ,EEDate DATE
    ,EEPriceDate DATE
    ,EEPrice DECIMAL(9,3)
    ,EEPriceSek DECIMAL(9,3)
);DECLARE
@PriceDataActive TABLE(
    StructuredProductId INT
    ,ActiveDate DATE
    ,ActivePriceDate DATE
    ,ActivePrice DECIMAL(9,3)
    ,ActivePriceSek DECIMAL(9,3)
)
```